# Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() when using active records in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Call to a member function on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)
> [Call to a member function on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254291/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)

When i try to access the database using CodeIgniters Active records it always gives me the error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

below is the settings in my database

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'test';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and i have auto-loaded it

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

and below is my model

```
class Leads_model extends CI_Model {
    
function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
    
    function insertq(){
        
        $q=$this->db->insert('test',$data);
        
        if ($q){
            
            return true;
        }       
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

can someone please suggest me what am i doing wrong and why am i getting that error?

Comment: Where are you calling $this->db->get()? Are you sure it refers to this model?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\quest\application\models\leads_model.php on line 14 . I call the $this->db->get() when the form is been submitted. The view loads fine from the controller but when i submit the for i get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i had added some variables to get the autocomplete work in to the model core. That was causing the problem and its working after removing those.

but the auto complete doesn't seem to work now.

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling the parent constructor?

```
class Leads_model extends CI_Model 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty strange indeed.
Make sure:
1) your error refers to that model, and not to another one;
2) you call the __construct() in your Model

If both of this checks are passed, try in-time loading and see if the problem persists:

```
class Leads_model extends CI_Model {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function test()
  {
    $this->load->database();
    $data = array('field1' => 'value1','field2' => 'value2');
    $this->db->insert('test',$data);
  }

  function run_test()
  {
     $dbo = $this->load->database('default',TRUE);
     $query = $this->$dbo->get('tablename');
     echo $query->num_rows();
  }

}
```

You can also see if the functions returns the connection id, as a test:

```
  $dbobject = $this->load->database('default',TRUE);
  var_dump($dbobject->conn_id);
```

Comment: when i dump i get "resource(33) of type (mysql link persistent)"

Comment: Ok, so the class works perfectly, and the connection is established. Could you try running the `run_test()` function I suggested above AS IS (just changing to your tablename, obv). See if it still gives errors

Comment: i added some variables to the model core to get the auto complete work. after i remove that everything works fine. Thanks a lot for the help. but the auto complete in eclipse doesn't work.

Comment: Change IDE or start typing out of habit then :D And beware when you change cores!